# rsync multiple files with spaces in their names

Tags: rsync

I'm trying to rsync txt files from a folder to another folder but the trouble is that many of these files have names that contain spaces. As such I keep on getting an error. What exactly do I need to do to have the script understand the spaces as such without having to spell out the name for each file that has spaces? FWIW, this is on MacOS.

```
do shell script "rsync `find /Volumes/HD/Users/123/Desktop/Test/ -type f -mtime -3` --include='*.txt' --exclude='*' --ignore-existing -raz --progress /Volumes/HD/Users/123/Desktop/TXT/"
```

Comment: `rsync -from0 $(find /Volumes/HD/Users/123/Desktop/Test/ -type f -mtime -3 -name *.txt -print0) --ignore-existing -raz --progress /Volumes/HD/Users/123/Desktop/TXT/` but why run `find` when `rsync` can traverse directories recursively? `rsync --exclude='*' --include='*.txt' --ignore-existing -azHvu --progress /Volumes/HD/Users/123/Desktop/Test/ /Volumes/HD/Users/123/Desktop/TXT/`

Comment: Thanks for the effort but I get the following error with your first suggestion:
Unknown filter rule: `rom0'
rsync error: syntax or usage error (code 1) at /BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/rsync/rsync-47/rsync/exclude.c(765) [client=2.6.9]

With the second it seems to run empty without producing anything and there is no -mtime -3 to capture the last 3 entries.

Comment: It's a typo error on my part. Missing hyphen `-`. It should be `--from0` or `-0` for short.

Comment: For the second option, it wasn't working because the parent directories of the text files are getting excluded. Try `rsync --include='*.txt' --include='**/' --exclude='**' --ignore-existing -azHvu --progress /Volumes/HD/Users/123/Desktop/Test/ /Volumes/HD/Users/123/Desktop/TXT/`

Comment: Hmmm, for the first solution now im getting the following: "building file list ... 
 0 files...
1 file to consider
drwxr-xr-x          68 2015/11/20 08:34:30 L2

sent 71 bytes  received 20 bytes  182.00 bytes/sec
total size is 0  speedup is 0.00